# Making conditions and talking about later result

Tags: tense

We normally use the future tense in the main clause and the present tense in the subordinate clause when we're making condition. But we use the future tense both in the main and the subordinate clause we we're talking about later results rather than conditions. My question is how can I distinct these two kind of `if-clause`s? For instance:

> I'll give you 100 pounds if it'll help you to go on holiday.

As far as I understand first I shall give 100 pounds to someone. And that they'll probably go on holiday is a future event regarding to giving 100 pounds. Right?

Comment: Yes, "if it will help".   Will + infinitive=future.  I will attend Moscow University next year.  But you could also say, "if it would help."  "If" is buddy-buddy with the subjunctive.

Comment: One way to understand *"X will do this if ..."* is to rephrase it to *"X is willing to do this if ..."* (or *"X is going to do this if ..."*). This is essentially different from *"If A happens, B will happen"*. Another way to understand it is to think of it as a nested conditional statement: *"I'll do this if that will happen [ if (because) I do this ]."*

Comment: @DamkerngT. That's if an action in subordinate clause  happens after an action in the main clause (perhaps as a result of the main clauses's action, but not necessary one), we use _will_ both in the main and subordinate clauses, do we?

Comment: Yes, I think you can put it that way. Another way to understand this is possibly using a more straightforward sentence: *"If I do this and it will help you, I'll do it."* The part *It will help you*, which can be rephrased as *if it'll help you* as in your example, sounds natural with *will* because the speaker can't state it with absolute certainty (whether it helps the other or not). Hence, the *will*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. By now I understand, thank you. Why don't you post your comments as an aswer?

Answer (score 1):

We use will in both the if-clause and the main clause in two different senses which are as follows:

1- When we want to request somebody politely to do something such as if you'll give me five minutes, I'll finish my work.

2- When we think and/or the person we are talking to thinks what is offered 
   will fullfil the desired results rather than a condition such as I'll 
   give you 100 pounds if it'll help you to go on holiday.